# How to fix No provider for ChangeDetectorRef! in Karma-Jasmine Testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

> StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MatTable -> ChangeDetectorRef]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatTable -> ChangeDetectorRef]:      NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MessagesComponent } from './messages.component';
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '../../../MessageUtility/node_modules/@angular/material';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterTestingModule  } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('MessagesComponent', () => {
  let component: MessagesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MessagesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MessagesComponent ],
    imports:[HttpClientModule,RouterTestingModule,MatTableModule, ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessagesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add some code

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to provide all required methods of `ChangeDetectorRef` as part of your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` declaration.

For example if your code (or a 3rd library like in your case) uses the `detectChanges` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef` instance you can provide it as in the following example:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                // other providers here
                { provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useValue: { detectChanges: () => { } } }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` as your Change Detection Strategy? ChangeDetectorRef is actually exposed to the fixture, as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#componentfixture-properties).

If you have defined ChangeDetectorRef as one of your private attributes in your component like this:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

Since it is private, you should create a spy as a stub for that attribute in your test file, and test if the ChangeDetectorRef is being called. Simply mock the CDR on your .spec file by doing this:

```
it('test CDR', () => {
  const spyCDR = spyOn((component as any).cdr, 'detectChanges'); 

  component.method();    
  expect(spyCDR).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```